# How do I enable InfoPath services in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-2013, infopath-forms-services

I'm having a problem with enabling InfoPath form services in SharePoint Central Administration.
I have SharePoint 2013 standard edition. I thought I could enable in the same way as in 2010 with help of this link:

http://www.sharepointassist.com/2010/06/15/wheres-infopath-forms-services-in-sharepoint-2010/

But I don't have a BIN file so I can not complete the way if I would type this in the commando prompt:

c:\program files\common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\bin\stsadm -o installfeature -name IPFSAdminWeb

If you know how to enable it and answer me I would be grateful!

Best regards
Malin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the given below link

it may help you

http://www.appvity.com/blogs/post/2013/06/16/How-to-configure-and-publish-InfoPath-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx

Comment: This doesn't answer the question if you want to open and edit an Info Path form in browser (without Info Path Designer)

Comment: The link clearly mention Enterprise edition is required while OT is using standard edition

Comment: InfoPath services are not available on the standard version